# How to follow a person using facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I follow a person using Graph API?
I'm using below code to Like a post

```
$facebook->api("/".$id."/likes", 'POST');
```

I want such code to follow a person 
something like:

```
$facebook->api("/".$id."/follow", 'POST');
```

Comment: have you solved your problem?? is there any way to follow??

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible VIA the API. [The documentation for the user endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#subscribers) only mentions getting a list of users who follow a specific user. For that they use this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/subscribers
```

Here is an excerpt from the docs:

> Read
>
> You can read the subscribers for a user for your app by issuing an
>   `HTTP GET` request to `/USER_ID/subscribers` with the user `access_token`
>   with the `user_subscriptions` or `friends_subscriptions` permission.